# os.listdir() in Python when listing files from network drive uses too much memory/takes long time

Tags: python, caching, networking, glob, listdir

I am trying to use os.listdir('somefilepath') to list files in a network drive. Despite the fact the number of files is not too large (around 3000 small files in the directory), the task just takes forever/does not finish. When I look at task manager, python takes ever increasing amount of memory to complete the task.

I have tried using os.walk instead, an glob.glob/glob.iglob functions but it does not help. 
Is there an issue with the network latency? What is the best way to check?

Comment: 3000 files would be very quick to find on disk. The problem you are describing is almost certainly network latency related.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a tool , preferably through python, that I can use to check?

Comment: preferably? actually you want a non-python tool to verify that the behaviour has nothing to do with python. how about good old `ls / dir`?

Comment: _python takes ever increasing amount of memory_ - this sounds like a bug in your program, not the network file system. Does it work with 3000 files on a local file system? Try the `os.listdir` in the python shell - does it work?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Using ls / dir : I use windows so I assume you are asking me to do ls/dir on the command line. The folder is on the network so I cannot navigate to the network folder via cd command (and than do ls)?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, it works on local. Also, I did try os.listdir in the iPython shell

Comment: @tdelaney Also, not sure what you mean bug in my program. As I mentioned, I litteraly copied os.listdir('somepath') in python shell.

Comment: I should also mention that the strange thing is that when I delete some files (say 500 files so that there are only 3500, not 4000 files) the os.listdir gives answer in half a second. But, when I add some back 500  files it just does not compile. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scandir` which is available in Python 3. It should perform better.

code might look something like this:

```
import os

file_list = os.scandir('your_dir_path')
```

see [scandir 1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) and [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)

Comment: I asked a similar question about 'os.listdir' performance. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429978/measure-progress-time-left-while-os-listdir-is-generating-a-list-python)