# measure progress (time left) while os.listdir is generating a list (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, listdir

In Python 2.7, I am using `os.listdir` to generate a list of files in a folder. There are lots of files and my connection to the folder is slow so it can take up to 30 seconds to complete. Here is an example:

```
import os
import time

start_time = time.time()
dir_path = r'C:\Users\my_name\Documents\data_directory'   #example path
file_list = os.listdir(dir_path)

print 'it took', time.time() - start_time, 'seconds'
```

This is for a Tkinter GUI I'm working on and I would like make a status bar showing how much time or percentage is left for this step that takes a long time (about 30 seconds).

Is there a way to show the time left or percentage left to complete the `file_list = os.listdir(dir_path)` step???

Comment: If the delay in `listdir` is because "your connection to the folder is slow", this seems outside the scope of `listdir` or python in general.  The (presumably) network-imposed delay is handled by your OS and transparent to python, so to answer your question, no, at least not easily.

Comment: Can't think of a way to create a "real" loading bar that would display the actual progress. It is doable, but I can only think of things that would really slow things down. So I would propose to create a fake loading bar that would update itself no matter the progress. You can roughly estimate how fast it should move and work it out yourself. You can run the `listdir` and fake loading bar in separate threads so both would be updated properly. But yeah, that's not a real answer, just a hacky thought.

Comment: Thank you for responding. the folder is located on a server that I have a shared connection to. I can't do anything to improve the connection but I will try putting the 'listdir' call in a separate thread so the GUI doesn't freeze up for those 30 seconds. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to use `scandir` which is only available with Python 3.

But there is a [back port.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir)

To understand the problem, read [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/).

Comment: This looks promising. I've been putting off switching to Python 3 since I can get by with 2.7, but I think it's time I make the switch.

Comment: it looks like there isn't a way to get the time left within python, but ultimately, I want to shorten this time and 'scandir' should help, so I'll give this answer the **check**